# Assigning roles to users in a Discord server upon joining

Tags: java, list, discord

I'm attempting to create a Discord game that runs on a server. Upon joining the server, the users who are wanting to play will type in !join in the message section of Discord. Upon reading that !join has been entered, Discord will randomly assign 1 of 5 character roles to that person.

I have stored the roles within a list, and have tried to make use of a randomizer that will pick one at random. I have attempted to write the code for this, however I am struggling to finish it. I have attached what I have attempted so far.

```java
List<String> givenList = Arrays.asList("banker", "artist", "lawyer", "noble", "spy");
Random rand = new Random();
String randomElement = givenList.get(rand.nextString(givenList.size()));

if (msg.equals("!join")){
        String role = name.guild.roles.find('name', randomElement);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I see that you added "discord" as a tag and to your title, while the program simply chooses a random element from a list. This may significantly limit the answers you get, bc. "discord" is way more specific.
It would be helpful to include any errors you get or how your code doesn't behave as expected.
Make sure to also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Without any other info, this seems OK, except that there is no method called `nextString` on Random and that you will need an integer here, so `nextInt`.
It's not clear to me what type "name" has.

Comment: You may want to rethink the usage of the command `!join` as it's already used by many discord bots, which are highly popular. In order to not interfere with others, you may want to come up with something easy, but more specific.

The process you're doing has two steps - pick a random element from the array and assign a role to the player. I suppose you can find an answer to managing roles from Discord API docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro